# Rally Subversion Connector not robust at finding artifacts

Tags: ruby, rally

Some of our engineers are finding that the Rally-Subversion connector does not do a very good job of finding artifacts in the commit message, for example if they are followed by a colon (e.g. DE2222:)

I took a look at the connector 3.7 code, and found that they first split the message into words, but that splitting is done like this:

```
words = message.gsub(/(\.|,|;)/, ' ').split(' ')
```

Is there any reason this would not be done like this:

```
    words = message.split(/\W+/)
```

This seems like it will be much more robust and I'm having trouble thinking of a downside.

Any reason we should not make this change?

If not, could this update please also be made in the next release of the connector as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the SCM connector source code is open, there's really no reason you shouldn't make a change to the commit message artifact "detection" regex, if you find it more efficient.

As a heads-up, Rally's new generation of SCM connectors (we're calling them "VCS" connectors for Version Control System connectors) will no longer utilize a post-commit hook, but instead will run at a scheduled interval and will collect commit events from the SVN log. These collected events will then be posted to Rally as Changesets.

The new VCS connectors will not parse the logs for commit messages to translate into artifact state changes - so ultimately implementing that type of functionality will end up needing a customer-extension to the connector code in the long run anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info on what's coming.  Did you by chance take a glance at the code in msgripper.rb and confirm that this change would not break anything?  I don't know ruby, so I was looking for confirmation that I was not breaking anything...

Comment: I tested your exact change, i.e. `words = message.gsub(/(\.|,|;)/, ' ').split(' ')` -> `words = message.split(/\W+/)` in msgripper.rb in a test instance of the SVN connector 3.7, and confirmed that it will still take a commit message such as "DE1 Fixed" and properly map the commit to a Rally Changeset. So it doesn't break anything. However, I admittedly did not thoroughly test the efficacy of your adjustment in the RegEx. I.E. in my testing, `/\W+/` still didn't capture such delimiters as colons, commas, etc.